# Where Weblogic stores all configurations

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c, application-server

I have application deployed on Weblogic. It is actually cluster, which consist of admin and two nodes with application deployed.

I want to write script that will update some few parameters, related to TLS, ports as post step.

For example, after execution of this script - it will change port numbers and keystore locations and restart cluster.

**1. My question is where weblogic stores all configurations?**

**2. Is there some file that includes all configurations, could my script for example modify this file and restart weblogic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config for each domain (in this case base_domain) is stored in a location such as \Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\config.xml.